# selenium `wait.until` not waiting till provided path gets render on DOM

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am testing angular based application using selenium, I wanted to process some test case over DOM. Before processing over the DOM, I'm waiting till it gets render using `wait.Until` method by providing `XPATH/Selector`. You can see below Code snippet which I used in my code.

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//[@id='stepsGrid'));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='stepsGrid']")).Click();
```

But `wait.Until` code get fired up before DOM gets renders, so my test case gets failed. Any Insight on it.

Isn't a `wait.Until` correct method to wait till DOM gets render?

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had smilar problems with it when the DOM gets updated the old one i think is removed and a new one replaces it. Since it is removed there is no object left to wait for and due to that it fires.

A ugly hack is to just include a Thread.Sleep(x) but i would not recommend it in production code.

Some time it can help placing another one right after the first one to try and catch the new object when it loads. Or maybe try and target another object to wait on and then get the correct object you need to use.

but yah it is a irritating bug and the answer depends on how the site acts and loads.

Comment: we can't predict how much time DOM will take to render..? and doing that `hard-code` time in code would be not good way to go..

Comment: Sadly, no. Its a work around to get past that part to continue coding until you can get a permanent fix in.

Answer (score 0):

`wait.Until` doesn't wait until the DOM is fully loaded, only until the condition is met, in your case the element is clickable.

`wait.Until` returns the `WebElement` it was waiting for, try clicking on that element instead of relocating it

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("stepsGrid"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
    {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
        {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };

    try
    {
        wait.until(expectation);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='stepsGrid']")).Click();
    }
    catch(Throwable error)
    {
        assertFalse("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete.",true);
    }
```

You can wait for the document to get ready and the perform your selenium click...